# Packetbeat failed to connect to backoff

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, packetbeat

I have a simple express app with Nginx and I use Filebeat with ELK stack. Filebeat takes in charge of streaming log file from Nginx to Logstash then processing it and visualize to Kibana. This pipeline works fine. However, I wanted to check how can I incorporate Packetbeat to this pipeline to check the different possibilities that gives to me.

My `docker-compose.yml` is the following:

```yaml
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    expose: 
      - "5044"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  app:
    build : ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules/ # make node_module empty in container
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - elk

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - app:app
    depends_on: 
      - app
    networks:
      - elk

  filebeat:
    build: ./filebeat
    entrypoint: "filebeat -e -strict.perms=false"
    volumes:
      - ./filebeat/config/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - app
      - nginx
      - logstash
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
    links: 
      - logstash

  packetbeat:
    build:
      context: packetbeat/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    command: -e --strict.perms=false
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./packetbeat/config/packetbeat.yml
        target: /usr/share/packetbeat/config/packetbeat.yml
        read_only: true
    user: packetbeat
    cap_add:
      - NET_RAW
      - NET_ADMIN
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
      - app
      - nginx
      - logstash

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

The `packetbeat.yml` for configuration is the following:

```yaml
packetbeat.interfaces.device: any

packetbeat.flows:
  timeout: 30s
  period: 10s

packetbeat.protocols.dns:
  ports: [53]
  include_authorities: true
  include_additionals: true

packetbeat.protocols.http:
  ports: [80, 5601, 9200, 8080, 8081, 5000, 8002]

packetbeat.protocols.memcache:
  ports: [11211]

packetbeat.protocols.mysql:
  ports: [3306]

packetbeat.protocols.pgsql:
  ports: [5432]

packetbeat.protocols.redis:
  ports: [6379]

packetbeat.protocols.thrift:
  ports: [9090]

packetbeat.protocols.mongodb:
  ports: [27017]

packetbeat.protocols.cassandra:
  ports: [9042]

processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~

setup.kibana:
  host: "kibana:5601/kibana"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "changeme"

file:
  path: "./packetbeat"
  filename: packetbeat
  rotate_every_kb: 10000
  number_of_files: 7

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
  username: "elastic"
  password: "changeme"

logging:
      files:
           rotateeverybytes: 10485760
```

The error that I am getting is the following:

```
022-05-17T07:27:04.701Z        ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://elasticsearch:9200)): Get http://elasticsearch:9200: lookup elasticsearch on 192.168.65.5:53: no such host
```

Any idea of where is the mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't your packetbeat be on the same network as elasticsearch ? `elk` in your case ?

Comment: Btw what version of elasticsearch are you targeting ?

Comment: `ELK_VERSION=7.3.1`

Comment: I changed `network_mode: host` to `networks: elk`, and  I got ```2022-05-21T18:57:21.766Z        ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://logstash:5044)): dial tcp 172.18.0.6:5044: connect: connection refused```

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from `Packetbeat`, in your config they are no mention of `Logstash` nor the port `5044`

Comment: The error comes from the logs of packetbeat by doing ‘docker logs’ and the name of the packetbeat container